# Are 'Functional Dependency' and 'Normalization' same things or different?

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization

Are 'Functional Dependency' and 'Normalization' same things with two different names?

[This guy says that.](http://www.emunix.emich.edu/~khailany/files/Normalization.htm)

Answer (score 2):

They're not the same thing.

*Functional dependency* describes a characteristic of two sets of attributes. For example, if you're given a country's [officially assigned two-letter ISO country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements), you also know the country name. You might say "The officially assigned two-letter ISO country code determines the country name." In relational notation, you might write that as A->B, read out loud as "A determines B", where A represents the ISO code, and B represents the country's name.

*Normalization* is a process of changing a relation from a less-desirable structure to a more-desirable structure. In the lower normal forms, those changes are based on functional dependencies.

Kent's paper, [*A Simple Guide to Five Normal Forms in Relational Database Theory*](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm), is probably a better reference for you right now.